# Add padding to table (Maintain cell collapsed)

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables, spacing

I'm making a table with a border between each row, I've been trying to edit the table so the row borders don't touch the outer border of the table and I can't figure it out for the life of me. I feel like there's probably a solution that I have completely overlooked.

What I'd like it to look like:

[image]

What it looks like at the moment:

[image]

Comment: You need to also post the HTML and CSS you have in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***IF*** the borders are set to `TD` inner elements

```
tr td:first-child {
     padding-left:25px;
}
tr td:last-child {
     padding-right:25px;
}
```

***Otherwise*** a nice way to do it would be to use a **transparent table** inside a
**gray DIV** that has the padding you need

```css
.tableContainer{
  padding:15px;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#353033;
  border:1px solid #000;
  box-shadow:0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

table{
  color:#B3B3B3;
  table-layout:fixed;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%;
}

td, th{
  text-align:left;
  padding:5px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

/* --------------------- */

html, body{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  font: 16px/1 sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#6da5ce+0,9c7bac+50,ec8e99+100 */
background: #6da5ce; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  #6da5ce 0%, #9c7bac 50%, #ec8e99 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,#6da5ce), color-stop(50%,#9c7bac), color-stop(100%,#ec8e99)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #6da5ce 0%,#9c7bac 50%,#ec8e99 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  #6da5ce 0%,#9c7bac 50%,#ec8e99 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  #6da5ce 0%,#9c7bac 50%,#ec8e99 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #6da5ce 0%,#9c7bac 50%,#ec8e99 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6da5ce', endColorstr='#ec8e99',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

```html
<div class="tableContainer">
  
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text goes here</td>
      <td>and here also</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, the transparent table inside the grey DIV was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Wren You'e welcome. Added a demo if it helps... Happy coding.

Comment: @Wren please next time when you ask questions, try **always** to add some code. A piece of code often speaks more than an image and helps people to help you.

Comment: Much appreciated, I apologise for not including the code in my post and I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: @OrunBhuiyan thanks for the thumbs up :) He's probably new to SO, he'll learn in time

Answer (score 0):

```
.tableContainer {
    padding: 15px 0px;}
td, th {
    padding: 5px 10px;}
```

Comment: Some commentary is usually appreciated